# SQL QUERY SELECT ...COUNT(...)>5

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following tables:

```
USER(iduser, fname, lname);

TRANSACTION(idtrans,iduser,iddoc,datetrans);
```

I have to list all the users that have more than 5 borrowed documents, so I did this:

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname
FROM USERS u, TRANSACTION t
WHERE t.iduser=u.iduser HAVING count(t.iduser)>5;
```

BUT I get this error

> not a single-group group function

Is there any other method to write this query?

Comment: Please use Group By clause with Having Clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'm really concerned by a table called TRANSACTION as it has special meaning in SQL. I'm not sure which database you're using, but notice that SO's MArkdown thinks TRANSACTION is a keyword rather than a table name

You can't use an aggregate function, or a HAVING clause without using a GROUP BY statement. Try this:

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname
FROM USERS u, TRANSACTION t
WHERE t.iduser=u.iduser
GROUP BY i.fname, u.lname
HAVING count(t.iduser)>5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname
FROM USERS u, TRANSACTION t
WHERE t.iduser=u.iduser 
GROUP BY u.fname, u.lname
HAVING count(t.iduser)>5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

SELECT u.fname, u.lname
FROM USERS u INNER JOIN TRANSACTION t ON t.iduser=u.iduser WHERE count(t.iduser)>5;

I just converted it to use inner join instead